# In Rails, # frozen_string_literal: true directive conflicts with StripParams

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, string, parameters

Using magic_frozen_string_literal, I added # frozen_string_literal: true to all files in app, config and lib/tasks folder and it's subfolders in my Rails 4.2 app. However, StripParams gem causes an error - "can't modify frozen String".

I removed # frozen_string_literal: true from application_controller.rb but still got the same error.

How can I make an exception so that StripParams gem works? Here's the code from the gem. v.strip! is the issue.

```
module StripParams
  def self.all!(params)
    params.each do |k, v|
      if v.respond_to? :strip!
        v.strip!
      elsif v.respond_to? :each_pair
        all!(v)
      end
    end
    params
  end
end
```

Comment: You're trying to use a [gem](https://github.com/smiller/strip_params) made seven years ago, four years before [Ruby 2.3.0](https://www.ruby-lang.org/en/news/2015/12/25/ruby-2-3-0-released/) was released. I would not recommend you use an ancient gem that never got beyond v0.0.1 with a straightforward incompatibility with the version of Ruby you're using.

Comment: It turned out that routes.rb caused the problem. { format: 'json' } has a string literal which goes into the params and thus causes the error. I changed it into { format: +'json' } and it solved the problem.